# Kotlin access file in project

Tags: android, kotlin

i would like to access a file available in my kotlin project but i can't figure out which path i should use ? Here is what i tried :

```
val afile = File("src/main/java/com/example/presskit/assets/file.png")
println(afile.exists())
```

I have tried with different path but i always get false. When i go to terminal and type pwd to have the full path i get : /Users/username/Desktop/test/android/framework/app/src/main/java/com/example/presskit/Lib

What part of this path should i use ? i have tried in many ways but it's doesn't work.

Comment: There is no path. Use `AssetManager` and its `open()` method.

Comment: i need to use asset manager Although my file isn't in asset folder ?

Comment: You first need to move that file to `src/main/assets/file.png`.

Comment: The way you are using is not valid. Please use this   val sImg = context.assets.open("file.png")